# Создать примитивный парсер математических выражений

Tags: c#, парсер, синтаксический-анализ, antlr

Есть строки:

```
string f1 = "sin(x)^2+662^2";
string f2 = "e^2+e^5";
```

После операций замены необходимо получить:

```
f1 == "Math.Pow(sin(x),2)+Math.Pow(662,2)"
f2 == "Math.Exp(2)+Math.Exp(5)"
```

Моя цель создать примитивный парсер математических выражений. Как я понимаю выполнить мою задачу реально через Regex, но составить pattern для замены я не могу

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводится к завершению задач за автора. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь решить сложную задачу негодными средствами. Вам нужен парсер арифметических выражений.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12):

Для начала строим синтаксический и лексический анализаторы (парсер и лексер). Возьмём для этого ANTLR4.

```
grammar Calculator;

/// Parser

prog: expr+ ;

expr : expr '^' expr                  # Pow
     | expr op=('+'|'-') expr         # AddSub
     | expr op=('*'|'/') expr         # MulDiv
     | VAL                            # Val
     | fun=('sin'|'cos') '(' expr ')' # Function
     | '(' expr ')'                   # Parens
     ;

/// Lexer

VAL : [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )?;
MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
POW : '^';
SIN : 'sin';
COS : 'cos';
WS  : (' '|'\r'|'\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Дальше с помощью паттерна Visitor обходим синтаксическое дерево:

```
public class CalculatorVisitor : CalculatorBaseVisitor<string>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> FunctionMap = new Dictionary<int, string> {
        { CalculatorParser.SIN, "Math.Sin" },
        { CalculatorParser.COS, "Math.Cos" },
    };

    public override string VisitPow (CalculatorParser.PowContext context)
    {
        return "Math.Pow(" + Visit(context.expr(0)) + "," + Visit(context.expr(1)) + ")";
    }

    public override string VisitMulDiv (CalculatorParser.MulDivContext context)
    {
        return Visit(context.expr(0)) + context.op.Text + Visit(context.expr(1));
    }

    public override string VisitAddSub (CalculatorParser.AddSubContext context)
    {
        return Visit(context.expr(0)) + context.op.Text + Visit(context.expr(1));
    }

    public override string VisitVal (CalculatorParser.ValContext context)
    {
        return context.VAL().GetText();
    }

    public override string VisitFunction (CalculatorParser.FunctionContext context)
    {
        return FunctionMap[context.fun.Type] + "(" + Visit(context.expr()) + ")";
    }

    public override string VisitParens (CalculatorParser.ParensContext context)
    {
        return "(" + Visit(context.expr()) + ")";
    }
}
```

И наконец, преобразовываем строку:

```
const string input = "(1+1)^2*(2+2)^3+sin(10.5)^2";
Console.WriteLine(new CalculatorVisitor().Visit(
    new CalculatorParser(new CommonTokenStream(
        new CalculatorLexer(new AntlrInputStream(input)))).prog()));
```

Получаем на выходе:

```
Math.Pow((1+1),2)*Math.Pow((2+2),3)+Math.Pow(Math.Sin(10.5),2)
```

P.S. Ногами не пинать, первый раз в жизни вижу ANTLR.

Answer (score 2):

> Как я понимаю выполнить мою задачу реально через Regex

Нет. Точнее, не совсем. Предпросмотр назад должен позволить написать корректный парсинг, но, формально, регулярными выражениями такая задача не решается.

> Моя цель создать примитивный парсер математических выражений.

Вот его и надо создавать. Выражение парсится за один проход по нему. Возведение в степень немного усложняет задачу, если оно выполняется справа налево.

> C#

Если ты собираешься потом его программно скомпилировать получившуюся строку как код на C# (что вообще-то нехорошо), то лучше сделай то же самое, но как код на VB.NET - в нём не потребуются замены, про которые ты спрашиваешь.

Comment: C# поддерживает [\G](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), поэтому сам токинайзер пишется в несколько строк.

Comment: @KoVadim, токенайзер или парсер?

Comment: токинайзер - тот который разберет на токены. На шарпе никогда не пробовал, но на перле писал - это буквально по две строки на каждый тип токена. (если у нас числа, арифметика, скобки и функции - 8-9 строк кода).

А потом, обычной обратной польской записью ещё немного кода и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim, я про токенайзер и не спорю. А вот с парсером ничего хорошего не получится. Разбить на токены можно одной регуляркой (причём без \G), потом по ним пройти рекурсивной функцией и построить дерево (и без польской записи). Делал такое на шапре - вроде проблем не возникало :)

Comment: делая дерево Вы делаете ту же польскую запись, просто делаете это рекурсивно. А обратная польская запись тем и хороша, что она делает все без рекурсии. Но это дело вкуса и оперативки с процессором.

А вот как разделять одной регуляркой - это конечно интересно, я в принципе догадываюсь, но хотелось бы посмотреть на этот вариант.

Comment: @KoVadim Без рекурсии - это за счёт явного применения стека, насколько я помню. Возможно даже, двух стеков. По идее, любой рекурсивный алгоритм можно сделать нерекурсивным таким образом. Не разделять, а выбирать. Для токена есть вполне осмысленное определение, по которому можно сделать его выбор.  Что-то в таком духе: `\w+|([-+&|])\1|[-+*/=%&|^]=?|[()\[\]{}~!]` - берём список всех совпадений и по нему проходим.