# Какие инструменты лучше использовать для поиска по строке?

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

В одномерном массиве типа string, среди прочих, хранится математическая формула средней линии трапеции вида: "m = ( a + b ) / 2". Так же, существует одномерный массив типа string, в котором хранятся значения, с помощью которых мы должны определить, хватит ли нам этих значений для вычисления выражения из предыдущего массива или нет, например: "a", "b". То есть, грубо говоря, проверить, вычисляется ли "m" с помощью только "a" и "b", а не с помощью "a", "b" и "c".

Comment: И сразу вопрос: вам нужно упрощение выражений? Например, если у вас формула `m = a - a + b`, нужно ли определять, что достаточно только `b`? Если да, задача становится **намного** сложнее.

Comment: Нет, этого не нужно. Вообще, в первом массиве записаны только стандартные формулы, т.е. таких значений, как вы написали там нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен в любом случае парсер формул.

Как его написать, описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/10105) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423283/10105). Распарсив строку, вы получаете либо ошибку (и значит, строка не содержит формулы), либо синтаксическое дерево. Обойдя его, вы можете найти список имён переменных.

Дальше тривиально: имея список имён, убеждаетесь, что все они встречаются в списке значений. На самом деле, распарсив формулу, вы сможете даже *подсчитать* результат, в зависимости от значений параметров.

(Да, ваша задача на самом деле очень сложная. Парсер — нетривиальная вещь.)