# Как распарсить строку с математической операцией?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка `"Amount>="`

Есть список операций в `List<string>`
`{"=","<>", ">", ">=","<", "<="}`

Как можно разделить строку на два значения `"Amount"` и `">="`

Проблема в том, что `Contains` или `Regex` находят операцию `=` и дальше и возвращают стоку типа `["Amount>", "="]`.

Comment: Сначала надо искать менее общее выражение, потом более общее, у меня работает такая ленивая регулярка `(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|>|<|=)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создать примитивный парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423283/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ```Regex.Split("Amount>=", @"(\W+)");```

Comment: Найдите книгу "Полный справочник по C#", Герберт Шилдт, 2004 год. Книга старая, всю её читать не рекомендую, но советую прочесть последнюю главу 26: "Синтаксический анализ методом рекурсивного спуска" - в ней приведён пример написания парсера математических выражений, которые могут включать скобки, переменные и пр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо greg zakharov.

Заюзал `Regex.Split("Amount>=", @"(\W+)");`

Для решение моей задачи подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Ооо, ну ты по адресу :3
Есть такая штука как [Обратная польская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) и если ты хочешь сделать что-то большее, чем просто одна операция, то она будет очень полезна, ты просто сначала переделываешь своё выражения по уже [готовым алгоритмам](https://master.virmandy.net/perevod-iz-infiksnoy-notatsii-v-postfiksnuyu-obratnaya-polskaya-zapis/) в польскую нотацию, а после по так же [готовым алгоритмам](https://master.virmandy.net/perevod-iz-infiksnoy-notatsii-v-postfiksnuyu-obratnaya-polskaya-zapis/) работаешь с ней.
А если тебе нужно просто сделать одну операцию, то твоя методика подойдёт, но ставь операции в массиве в порядке уменьшения количества символов, чтобы она искала сначала их)