# Простой консольный калькулятор

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vb.net

Имеется код калькулятора, который должен складывать/отнимать/умножать/делить два числа.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first digit... ")
    Dim x As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second digit... ")
    Dim y As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Choose operation(+, -, /, *)")
    If Console.ReadLine() = "*" Then
        Console.WriteLine(x * y)
        Console.ReadLine()
    ElseIf Console.ReadLine() = "/" Then
        Console.WriteLine(x / y)
        Console.ReadLine()
    ElseIf Console.ReadLine() = "+" Then
        Console.WriteLine(x + y)
        Console.ReadLine()
    ElseIf Console.ReadLine() = "-" Then
        Console.WriteLine(x - y)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub

End Module
```

Но происходит:
[image: Но происходит это]
После ввода знака операции с числами и трёх нажатий Enter командная строка пропадает.
Возможно, я не правильно присваивал значения переменным или не так вывел результат.

Comment: Ну а что Вы хотели? Сами написали такой код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Чтобы все работало, `*` надо ввести 1 раз; `/` - 2 раза, `+` - 3 раза, `-` - 4 раза

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, и правда, так работает. Не подскажите как ограничится одни символом?

Comment: товарищ, ну разве Вы не понимаете, что в Вашей цепочке `if-else` в каждом условии Вы инициируете новый ввод со стороны пользователя. Один раз считайте строку, засунув значение в переменную, а дальше проверяйте значение переменной)

Comment: И вот ассоциация по поводу калькуляторов - [я недавно отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867231/248572)

Comment: @Irvin, для запроса операции сделайте **один** `ReadLine` до блока `if`, запишите результат в переменную, а потом это значение переменной проверяйте внутри `if`.