# Умный калькулятор 2+2*2=6

Tags: java

Как мне сделать калькулятор, который будет считать по правилам арифметических действий, например 2+2*2=6 или 2+2/2=3. При этом моя программа должна заканчиваться всегда "=".

Мой код:

```
public class Kalkulator {

private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Задайте выражение: ");

    int v, a;
    char op;
    v = sc.nextInt();
    do {
        op = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (op != '=') {
            a = sc.nextInt();
            switch (op) {
                case '+':
                    v += a; break;
                case '-':
                    v -= a; break;
                case '/':
                    v /= a; break;
                case '*':
                    v *= a; break;

            }
        }

    } while (op != '=');
    System.out.println(v);
}
}
```

Сейчас она работает так:

```
input:
2 + 2 * 2 = 

output:
8
```

Comment: Почитайте про обратную польскую натацию. Например в моем [репозитории](https://github.com/iagulevich/IntervaleCalculate), есть реализация с приоритетами операций.

Comment: Почитайте в [моем старом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867231/248572) метод с использованием `ANTLR`. C# и Java - родственники, так что, думаю, Вы без особого труда сможете портировать мое решение на свой язык (вот [пример](https://m.habr.com/post/341138/) работы с ANTLR на Java с Хабра)

Comment: вам нужен синтаксический анализатор по методу рекурсивного спуска (recursive descent parser). Примеров море, например https://github.com/gorobec/Calculator