# Как получить полное число перед знаком

Tags: c#, строки, парсер

Мне нужно распарсить строку. Она может иметь один из вот таких видов:

```
0²
0²(+,-,*)0
0(+,-,*)0²
```

Где:

> 0 - число в диапазоне **[1;50]**

---

> ² - степень числа перед этим знаком. Мне нужно получить то число,
>   которое стоит до этого знака.

---

> (+,-,*) - на этом месте может быть или +, или -, или *. Никакого
>   другого знака там стоять не может.

Не могу получить число, которое возводиться в степень. Можно сделать вот так:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(expression [expression.IndexOf('²') - 1]);
```

Но такой подход негибкий, так как число может быть больше 10.

Вижу, некоторые не совсем поняли что я от вас хочу).

### Пример

### INPUT

```
"10+13²"

"11+4²"

"43²+3"
```

### OUTPUT

```
13

4

43
```

**Как мне усовершенствовать мой метод, что бы он находил полностью число, даже если оно больше 10?**

Comment: Может вам стоит пойти по [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423322/220553) пути?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а без ANTLR4 это возможно? Силами C#

Comment: Ну можно почитать еще ответы на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688781/220553) вопрос. А так, самое банальное что можно сделать - регулярные выражения. Я лично не напрягался не когда по этому вопросу и использовал уже готовые решения (благо в интернете их уйма). Ну а вообще, если просто получить число и вы точно знаете, что оно стоит всегда первым, то почему бы не сделать через `Split('²')[0]`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `0(+,-,*)0²` такой вариант, по-моему, не подойдет для варианта со `Split`

Comment: @SeeSharp, Можете написать несколько примеров?

Comment: @DIlshod да, пожалуйста

Comment: _([^\D]+)²_ (https://regex101.com/r/RgiKOY/3)  Не пойдет?

Comment: @LLENN извините за глупый вопрос. Я понял, по ссылке, что шаблон рабочий, но как мне имея строку получить число? Не совсем пойму какой метод использовать. Можете в ответ, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать регулярное выражение такого вида: `(?<DigitValue>[^\D]+)²`

Где `DigitValue` — название группы.

Чтобы использовать такой вариант, вам необходимо завести один объект `Regex`:

```
Regex digitDataRegex = new Regex("(?<DigitValue>[^\\D]+)²",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Далее, если входная данные многострочные, то вам необходимо будет крутить цикл получая данные из каждого найденного вхождения, например так:

```
string inputData = "2²\r\n3²(+,-,*)6\r\n1(+,-,*)7²\r\n\r\n10+13²\r\n11+4²\r\n43²+3";
Regex digitDataRegex = new Regex("(?<DigitValue>[^\\D]+)²",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
MatchCollection dataCollection = digitDataRegex.Matches(inputData);
foreach (Match match1 in dataCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Founded digit value: {0} at index {1} match data is {2}",
                match1.Groups["DigitValue"].Value, match1.Index, match1);
}
```

Comment: Все отлично, но мне возвращает со знаком в конце. Может где-то ошибка?

Comment: Да, забыл указать `Value` для группы.

Comment: Кстати, вы можете еще проверить вот так: `)²`, это не будет захвачено.

Comment: Да, все отлично работает. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Для полной обработки можно сделать простой конечный автомат, обрабатывающий символ за символом.

В начальном состоянии A значение `V = 0`

Получили цифру `digit` - вернулись в то же состояние, модифицировали

```
V = V * 10 + digit
```

Получили цифру в верхнем регистре - это степень, накопленное значение V -подстепенное число, перешли в состояние B, ожидаем конца строки или арифметического символа, или что там ещё возможно.

Если в состоянии A получили арифметический символ  - записали накопленное число, перешли в состояние C, значение V сбрасываем в 0, ждём цифру и т.д.

Главное-  правильно расписать возможные состояния и переходы

Comment: `expression = "10+12²"` вообще получаю `FormatExeption`